# Is gravitational lensing the only way to concentrate light without photons being absorbed and re-emitted?

Tags: electromagnetism

In other methods of concentrating light, the photons are absorbed and then emitted in a direction so that the photons converge upon a point. If we use gravitational lensing to concentrate light, are the photons not being absorbed and re-emitted?

Edit: By the way, another interpretation of Feynman diagrams is that photons are bouncing off of the electrons of the atoms of the lenses, rather than being absorbed and re-emitted. In that case, the question becomes "in gravitational lensing, do photons interact with any discrete particle in order to be concentrated"?

Comment: How about the two slit experiment?

Comment: 1) What 'other methods' are you referring to? 2) How do you differentiate between original and 'non-original' photons?

Comment: How about I rephrase the question so that it asks whether gravitational lensing is the only way to concentrate light without  involving the absorption and emission of photons?

Comment: As for other methods, we have typical lenses, and also electron lensing. All of these can be classified as lensing due to point charges absorbing and re-emitting photons.

Comment: Fresnel lens, [bierefringence](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birefringence), refractor telescopes are good approximations as long as you can’t see a redshift of the light on the outside

Comment: @HolgerFiedler, in all of these methods, light is concentrated because the photons are being absorbed and re-emitted by the electrons of the atoms of the material lenses being used.

Comment: Abdul, that’s right. My point was: As long, as you can’t measure the redshift, it does not matter.

Comment: I dont understand your point. Why does it not matter that photons are being absorbed and emitted or not when that is tge focus of the question?

Answer (score 4):

Any interaction process at all that changes a photon's momentum can be represented by a Feynman diagram with an ingoing and an outgoing photon as external legs. Whether they're "the same photon" is an entirely philosophical question, so your question can't be answered through physical arguments.

Comment: How about I rephrase the question so that it asks whether gravitational lensing is the only way to concentrate light without  involving the absorption and emission of photons?

Comment: Also, since gravity is the curvature of spacetime, can't we say that the photon's momentum is the same, but seems different due to being in curved spacetime? If not, can you draw a Feynman diagram showing the photon being absorbed and re-emitted?

Answer (score 0):

Lenses also focus light without photons being absorbed and reemitted.

Comment: Can you explain why?